# How to improve NODE.js pug templates development?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am a back-end developer, but recently a task of mine has been to develop a NODE.js project. While the server part seems fine to me, I am struggling to developing the front-end pages.
In order to simplify and compress these pages, I started to use pug (formerly jade). However, my pages simply look a bit too minimalist.

How can I improve such web page design? :)

I believe that there should be some better way of developing these pages rather than doing it only by "lines of text"... : \

Best regards,
Lorenzo

P.S. a pug "code" example which results in a blank web page with one gray button, two textboxes, and two labels:

```
html
  body
    form(action='/login', method='post')
      div
        label Username:
        |  
        input(type='text', name='username')
        br
      div
        label Password:
        |  
        input(type='password', name='password')
      div
        input(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is that your pages (or maybe source? im not sure) look too simple/small? I'd consider that a plus to be completely honest.
It would be nice if you could try and clarify your question more, maybe include some code.

Comment: Take a look on Bootstrap. Also. If you like jade, there are tools to convert html to jade so you can migrate bootstrap templates to jade.

Comment: @bitifet that looks interesting! Do you know if there is also some visual support (e.g. WYSIWYG)?

Comment: @Hoi_A s you stated the simplicity of the code it is not an issue; my problem is that my pages lack of "design", or "bells and whistles" :) For example, the code added in the main question results in a blank web page with two labels, two textboxes, and a gray button, which is not really "interesting" or "appealing". 
I wonder if there is any framework and/or tool to improve pug pages development and "design".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bitifet answered this question by proposing to use Bootstrap framework. Bootstrap framework provides an easy way to add "bells and whistels" to the web application.